# Azure - Java aplication

Tags: java, azure, azure-web-app-service

We are planning to deploy Java application ( using jax-ws) on Azure with Tomcat. But am not sure how to connect to On premises database on Azure in Java. Can someone please provide some pointers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will deploy your Java app in an Azure App Service, you have basically two options:

- [Use a hybrid connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-hybrid-connections)
- Use a [VNET integrated App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet) and connect to on-premise via VPN or Express Route

Comment: You have the right of it but for a full list of all of the networking features in App Service you can take a look at this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/app-service/networking-features.  
Keep in mind that we don't yet have Hybrid Connections out for Linux and that the older VNet Integration feature based on point to site is only available with Windows.